# Would a "shell function" or "alias" be appropriate for this use

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I'm currently trying to create an alias or shell function which I can run to check my battery life, in attempts to familiarize myself with aliases and bash. I have run into a problem where, I'm not receiving any feedback from my command and can not verify if it's working or if there are any steps i have left out that will give me my desired result.

Current `.bashrc` alias:

```
alias battery='upower -i $(upower -e | grep -e 'BAT'| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage")'
```

Desired use:

```
b@localhost:~$ battery
```

Desired result:

```
state: discharging Time to empty: x.x Hours percentage: xx%
```

I have read the bash references for something that might help me here. I wasn't able to find anything that I think applies here. Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: Run `source ~/.bashrc` and then type `type -a battery` and tell us what you see.

Comment: `type -a battery` `battery is aliased to 'upower -i $(upower -e | grep -e BAT | grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage")'`

Comment: That's not quite what I mean. `type -a` shows you everything that a command maps to. For example, if I type `type -a ls` into the terminal, I see the following:  (`@@` is newline).  `bash-4.4$ type -a ls @@ ls is aliased to \`/bin/ls -AF' @@ ls is /bin/ls`

Comment: Let me try again, There is nothing the command maps to past its alias defined in bashrc.

Comment: try replacing `'BAT'` with `"BAT"` inside the body of the alias.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet That doesn't make a difference, or why should it?

Comment: This worked. There was also a mistake in () placement `'upower -i $(upower -e | grep -e 'BAT' | grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage")'`  was supposed to be ` 'upower -i $(upower -e | grep -e "BAT") | grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage"' ` Thank you for your help. Would you know what part of the bash reference has information on this? or what its called to further read into this.

Comment: @BenjaminW. That's true. It doesn't affect the behavior in this case, but it is bad form. The characters inside `BAT` aren't actually quoted because the single quote mechanism don't know anything about command substitution `$(...)`

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Command substitutions begin a new quoting context; `BAT` is quoted (although unnecessarily) as an argument to `grep`.

Comment: @chepner `alias` is a shell builtin, not a shell keyword. In this case, there is one string being passed to the `alias` builtin (with alternating quoted and unquoted characters): `battery=` then `'upower -i $(upower -e | grep -e '` then `BAT` then `'| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage")'`.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Oh, now I understand. You're right.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Heh. I feel kind of bad for derailing bannji's question.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Ah, right, although the alias has nothing to do with it. The command substitution is in single quotes, so it never executes to create the new quoting context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @bannji already announced in a comment, he has fixed his command.
Old incorrect alias

```
'upower -i $(upower -e | grep -e 'BAT'| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage")'
```

New correct alias

```
'upower -i $(upower -e | grep -e "BAT") | grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage"'
```

Most comments were talking about the interpretation of the quotes. That was not the problem here. The main difference is where the subcommand is closed. In the first case the subcommand is closed after the last `grep`, su `upower -i` gets nothing.
In the second command the second `grep` will filter the output of `upower -i`.

The difference in quotes is interesting in an other example.

```
addone() {
    ((sum=$1+1))
    echo "${sum}" 
}
i=1
alias battery='addone $(addone $i)'
i=4
battery
# other alias
i=1
alias battery2='addone $(addone '$i')'
i=4
battery2
```

Both battery commands will try to add 2 to the value of `$i`, but will give different results.
The command `battery` will add 2 to the current value 4 of `$i`, resulting in 6.
The command `battery2` will add 2 to the value of `$i` at the moment that the alias was defined, resulting in 3.
Why?
In battery2 the string `$i` is surrounded by single quotes, but those single quotes are inside other ones. The result is that `$i` is evaluated and the alias is defined as

```
alias battery2='addone $(addone 2)'
```